# How to edit "Full Windows Folder Path Regular Expression"

Tags: regex, validation

Hay this regualr expression working fine for **Full Windows Folder Path**

```
^([A-Za-z]:|\\{2}([-\w]+|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\\(([^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20]|\.[.\x20]*[^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20])([^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x1F]*[^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x20])?))\\([^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20]([^"*/:?|<>\\\x00-\x1F]*[^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20])?\\)*$
```

**Matches**
`d:\`, `\\Dpk\T c\`, `E:\reference\h101\`, `\\be\projects$\Wield\Rff\`, `\\70.60.44.88\T d\SPC2\`

**Non-Matches**
`j:ohn\`, `\\Dpk\`, `G:\GD`, `\\cae\.. ..\`, `\\70.60.44\T d\SPC2\`

**PROBLEM:
THIS EXPRESSION REQUIRED "`\`" END OF PATH.
HOW CAN I EDIT THIS EXPRESSION SO USER CAN ENTER PATH LIKE 
`C:\Folder1`,  `C:\Folder 1\Sub Folder`**

Comment: Add a `?` after the last `\\ ` so that it would look like ...`-\x20])?\\?)*$` I am not saying this would work for all cases, but reading and understanding that regex is beyond the scope of this book if you will.

Comment: All your "non-matches" are valid paths on windows... I don't understand the purpose of this regular expression at all.

Comment: @Amargosh: I fear catastrophic backtracking on non-matches if you simply nest a `?` inside a `*`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: everything about this regex is a catastrophe.  Who wrote it?  Cthulhu?

Comment: Windows paths are usually limited to 32767 (wide) characters, with each individual level limited to 255 characters. The regex accepts overly-long paths. Adding those limits can reduce excessive backtracking. If you haven't seen a `\` in 256 characters, the regex should not match at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this problem:

- Understand the regex (way harder than necessary) and fix it to your specification (may be buggy)
- Who cares how the regex does its thing (it seems to do what you need) and modify your input to conform to what you think the regex does

The second approach means that you just check if the input string ends with `\`. If it doesn't then just add it on, then let the regex does it magic.

I normally wouldn't recommend this ignorant alternative, but this may be an exception.

---

#### Blackboxing

Here's how I'm "solving" this problem:

- There's a magic box, who knows how it works but it does 99% of the time
- We want it to work 100% of the time
- It's simpler to fix the 1% so it works with the magic box rather than fixing the magic box itself (because this would require understanding of how the magic box works)
- Then just fix the 1% manually and leave the magic box alone

---

#### Deciphering the black magic

That said, we can certainly try to take a look at the regex. Here's the same pattern but reformatted in free-spacing/comments mode, i.e. `(?x)` in e.g. Java.

```
^
( [A-Za-z]:
| \\{2}   ( [-\w]+
          | (
               (25[0-5]
               |2[0-4][0-9]
               |[01]?[0-9][0-9]?
               )\.
            ){3}
               (25[0-5]
               |2[0-4][0-9]
               |[01]?[0-9][0-9]?
               )
          )
  \\ (
       (    [^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20]
       |  \.[.\x20]* [^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20]
       )
       (    [^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x1F]*
            [^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x20]
       )?
     )
)
\\ ( 
         [^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20]
      (
         [^"*/:?|<>\\\x00-\x1F]*
         [^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20]
      )?
      \\
   )*
$
```

The main skeleton of the pattern is as follows:

```
^
(head)
\\ (
      bodypart
      \\
   )*
$
```

Based from this higher-level view, it looks like an optional trailing `\` can be supported by adding `?` on the two `\\` following the `(head)` part:

```
^
(head)
\\?(
      bodypart
      \\?
   )*
$
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Question Mark for Optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

---

#### Note on catastrophic backtracking

You should generally be *very* wary of nesting repetition modifiers (a `?` inside a `*` in this case), but for this specific pattern it's "okay", because the `bodypart` doesn't match `\`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: But what if adding the "\" makes it work with some paths it shouldn't?  I mean, without understanding, who knows whether it will start a global thermonuclear war?

Comment: @Borealid: Let's say `s` doesn't end with `'\'`. If it's true that the regex requires a terminating `'\'` to match, then it wouldn't have accepted `s` in the first place, so checking if `s + '\'` is accepted will not cause a false positive.

Comment: Let's say `s` is a string which is *correctly* not accepted currently, and `s+'\'` is an accepted string.  If you append '\' to all strings before processing, then `s` is now incorrectly accepted where it previously was not.  Thus, a false positive.

Comment: @polygenelubricants
Hay thanks Dear 
i already did that 
i added "\" in input string.

Comment: @Borealid: give an example of such `s`; I'm getting confused.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Let `s` be `/`.  `//` is a valid path, `/` is not, on Windows.

Comment: @Borealid: my proposal is to append `'\'` only if `s` doesn't already end with `'\'`. Your `s` ends with a different kind of slash (`'/'`), and you add yet another `'/'`. I'm getting even more confused.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your regular expression *at all*.  But I bet all you need to do is find the bit or bits that match the trailing "\", and add a single question mark after that bit or those bits.

Comment: Hay Thnx for your reply
I just found this expression from this website

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1785

Answer (score 1):

The regex you provided seems to mismatch "C:\?tmp" which is an invalid windows path.

I have figured out one solution but works in windows only. You may have a try with this one:

```
"^[A-Za-z]:(?:\\\\(?![\"*/:?|<>\\\\,;[\\]+=.\\x00-\\x20])[^\"*/:?|<>\\\\[\\]]+){0,}(?:\\\\)?$"
```

This regex ignores the last "\" which hinders you.

I've tested with pcre.lib(5.5) in VS2005.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is roughly 4 years old, but the following may be sufficient:

```
string validWindowsOrUncPath = @"^(?:(?:[a-z]:)|(?:\\\\[^\\*\?\:;\0]*))(?:\\[^\\*\?\:;\0]*)+$";
```

(to be used with IgnoreCase option).

Edit:
I even came to this one, which can extract the root and each part in named groups:

```
string validWindowsOrUncPath = @"^(?<Root>(?:[a-z]:)|(?:\\\\[^\\*\?\:;\0]*))(?:\\(?<Part>[^\\*\?\:;\0]*))+$";
```